# Deploy to bluemix failed with "Failed to query status of cloning repository operation."

Tags: ibm-cloud, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to setup a deploy to Bluemix button for a demo project.

The project has been deploying successfully today, but has now stopped deploying with the error:

> "Failed to query status of cloning repository operation.".

See below for a screenshot.

How can I debug this? No other information is provided in the output about the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problems appears to have just been a temporary glitch that has now rectified itself.  I'll leave the question and answer on stackoverflow in case this is useful for other users.